# Bootstrap forms and pagination getting messed up

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, bootstrap, joomla3.8.5

In my backend, all forms look like this:
[image]

Instead of how they used to look:
[image]

Comment: Have you changed the files in the administrator / templates folder?
Download joomla, replace the files in the templates folder.

Comment: Given the icons aren't loading properly I would guess you have something broken in your head tag.  Open dev tools in chrome and look for errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gitignore was ignoring the fonts and css folders inside media/jui. Adding these folders back solved the forms and icons issues.